# How can I get the current CodeDomProvider in an MSBuild Task

Tags: c#, msbuild, code-generation, task, codedom

I have a task and I want to generate some code using the CodeDom. How can I get either the current "language" or the CodeDomProvider for the current project calling my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I managed to figure it out eventually:

[Geting a CodeDomProvider in an MSBuild Task](https://justinmchase.com/2008/12/27/getting-a-codedomprovider-in-an-msbuild-task/)